# Piping emails from postfix under Plesk to Ostickets helpdesk

Tags: bash, email, pipe, postfix-mta

I'm trying to pipe support emails from my production mail server (Plesk 12 and Postfix) to send them to another VPS hosting my helpdesk installation, I have chosen ostickets helpdesk for many reasons (Open source,PHP/MySQL...)

So, the idea is to trigger email reception on some adresses such as contact@company.com, support@company.com... then resend them to ostickets via its API in order to create a new ticket there.

I tried this way 
http://blog.absolutedisaster.co.uk/osticket-plesk-9-postfix-pipe-mail-to-a-progr/

It explains how to create a pipe to trigger email, lunch php script ...etc

Because of some permission issues, I kept all this configuration and change just the last thing : php script

So I've replaced this php script by a simple bash script doing the same thing : send a request to API to create a new ticket via CURL.

Now In my production mail server the pipe is recognized and the email is trigged successfully :

[image: output /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog in mail server]

The same in the other side, osticket API is receiving the request:

[image: output /var/log/apache2/access.log in ostickets VPS]

The problem is that the http response is 400 as you can see, which means ans error code #66 in ostickets (malformed email).

So, I think the problem is in my bash script :

```
exec curl --header 'X-API-Key: API_KEY_HERE' --user-agent 'osTicket API Client v1.7' --data - 'http://support.company.com/api/tickets.email'
```

the original PHP script I have replaced by this is :

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

# Configuration: Enter the url and key. That is it.
#  url => URL to api/tickets.email e.g http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tickets.email
#  key => API's Key (see admin panel on how to generate a key)
#   

$config = array(
        'url'=>'http://support.company.com/api/tickets.email',
        'key'=>'API_KEY_HERE'
        );

#pre-checks
function_exists('file_get_contents') or die('upgrade php >=4.3');
function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
#read stdin (piped email)
$data=file_get_contents('php://stdin') or die('Error reading stdin. No message');

#set timeout
set_time_limit(10);

#curl post
$ch = curl_init();        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.7');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$result=curl_exec($ch);        
curl_close($ch);

//Use postfix exit codes...expected by MTA.
$code = 75;
if(preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $result, $status)) {
    switch($status[1]) {
        case 201: //Success
            $code = 0;
            break;
        case 400:
            $code = 66;
            break;
        case 401: /* permission denied */
        case 403:
            $code = 77;
            break;
        case 415:
        case 416:
        case 417:
        case 501:
            $code = 65;
            break;
        case 503:
            $code = 69;
            break;
        case 500: //Server error.
        default: //Temp (unknown) failure - retry 
            $code = 75;
    }
}

exit($code);
?>
```

What is missing in my bash script ? (especially the stdin input)

thank you so much,

**UPDATE** 
The problem was indeed in the bash script, here is the solution I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=`cat -`
exec curl --header 'X-API-Key: API_KEY_HERE' --user-agent 'osTicket API Client v1.7' --data "$data" 'http://support.company.com/api/tickets.email'
```

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it so that this no longer comes up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed in the bash script, here is the solution I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=`cat -`
exec curl --header 'X-API-Key: API_KEY_HERE' --user-agent 'osTicket API Client v1.7' --data "$data" 'http://support.company.com/api/tickets.email'
```